# Move doc from one sub site to another sub site by document name

Tags: workflow, document-library

**Scenario** - My field technicians are submitting PDF docs by email to a document center and a workflow then moves the doc from the drop off library to the correct branch office library.

We also have customer sites where each customers field data is stored.

How can I automatically move a customer report from the document center to the customers site by using the customers name or account number as a reference?

These customer sites are sub sites of the main site.

I have looked at the many articles on this site and others regarding moving whole sites, lists, libraries and even individual docs, but none regarding moving a specific doc by name to a sub site by name.

We have less than 50 customer sites and I assume that the code would have to read something like "IF doc name contains AA then copy doc to AA's site" and then if doc name contains BB then copy doc to BB's site etc etc
I also assume using jQuery would achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as per design. If you try to move documents to a different location using Retention policy, you have to move it a library in a different site collection. Preferably ‘Records center‘ site collection. Main idea of Microsoft is to have one Archival or Records center site collection for the whole organization.

If you need to move the document within the same site collection then there is a solution for it please go through below link,

http://sharepointviews.com/sharepoint-retention-policy-not-working-solved/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drop Off library and have a Record Center site, then the best way is to use **Content Organizer Rules** for routing documents to desired destination based on defined rules and matching criteris rather than workflows.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Content-Organizer-rules-to-route-documents-74dfe36d-e3d6-40b7-9a5c-beea0c84deed

Comment: Thanks for replying Clad. It's a bit more complicated than that. Content Organizer only allows you to move content within the particular site. I need to move the doc from the Record Centre to a particular customers sub site outside of the Records centre but still within the same site collection.